# Flexbox on my home page not working properly on IE 11

Tags: css, wordpress, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

My client reported an issue with me, which is flexbox not working on product card section on home page (WordPress site)
https://hailinpower.com/

This is what it looks like on Chrome:
screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

This is what it looks like on IE 11:
screenshot on IE 11:
[image: screenshot on IE 11]

I've searched for solutions but I was not able to fix it.
I tried to set a height: 589px to the flex container, also flex children div, but it didn't work...

I have added a custom CSS code to this section as below:

```
.home-page-row .kt-row-layout-inner .kt-row-column-wrap .wp-block-kadence-column .kt-inside-inner-col {

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
}
```

This custom CSS code might be the reason that causes this issue?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Hi Nico, it's designed with Ocean WP theme and Kadence Block, not my custom theme. And I have added this custom CSS code: 

.home-page-row .kt-row-layout-inner .kt-row-column-wrap .wp-block-kadence-column .kt-inside-inner-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your custom css

```
.home-page-row .kt-row-layout-inner .kt-row-column-wrap .wp-block-kadence-column .kt-inside-inner-col {

display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex: 1;
}
```

`flex: 1` to `flex-grow: 1`

I´ve done it on debug panel of IE11 and it worked, see the imagem below
[image]

Comment: Hi Vitor. Thanks for the answer. I tried that but didn't work though. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Thanks, let me try again real quick.

Comment: Hi Gwon, you can use as well flex: 1 0 auto;

Comment: Hi Victor. Sorry about before. I didn't have any cache plugin installed on this site, and then I went to Cloudways to clear the cache and then refresh and it work like a charm. Thank you so so very much! Clearly I know nothing about flexbox ...:(

Comment: No worries, I´m happy to help :)

Comment: Hey @GwonZhang would you mind check my answer as a correct one and give it an up vote? Thanks :)

Comment: Hey Vitor, I've clicked the up arrow, did I do it right? This is the first time I'm using stackoverflow.

Comment: Hey @GwonZhang you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sorry Vitor, did I get it right this time?